# Java Regex - Conditional Grouping

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds

I need to parse the following lines in 2 groups:

Group 1: ADJ-1-37-10

Group 2: 3.00 (if there's no SPANLOSSMARGIN tag then it should be empty)

So far I used `"(ADJ-\d{1,3}-\d{1,3}-\d{1,3})::.*?SPANLOSSMARGIN=(\d{1,2}.\d{1,2})` to parse the following lines. But it's not matching the ADJ-1-37-16 as the line doesn't contain the SPANLOSSMARGIN tag. My requirement is when there's ADJ-X-XX-XX tag (irrespective of the presence of other tags) then Group 1 should return it and when there's is SPANLOSSMARGIN tag then Group 2 should return it; but only when there's no SPANLOSSMARGIN tag, Group 2 should return empty. How can I achieve this?

```
"ADJ-1-2-5::FIBERTYPE=NDSF,OSCSPANLOSS=16.00,TARGSPANLOSS=16.00,MINSPANLOSS=0.00,SPANLOSSMARGIN=3.00"
   "ADJ-1-13-5::FIBERTYPE=NDSF,OSCSPANLOSS=16.00,TARGSPANLOSS=16.00,MINSPANLOSS=0.00,SPANLOSSMARGIN=3.00"
;
   "ADJ-1-37-2::FIBERTYPE=UNKNOWN,TARGSPANLOSS=0.00,MINSPANLOSS=0.00,SPANLOSSMARGIN=3.00,SPANLOSSSOURCE=UNKNOWN,BUNDLEID=\"\",LINEIN=\"\",LINEOUT=\"\",CRSIN=\"\",CRSOUT=\"\""
   "ADJ-1-37-4::FIBERTYPE=UNKNOWN,TARGSPANLOSS=0.00,MINSPANLOSS=0.00,SPANLOSSMARGIN=3.00,SPANLOSSSOURCE=UNKNOWN,BUNDLEID=\"\",LINEIN=\"\",LINEOUT=\"\",CRSIN=\"\",CRSOUT=\"\""
   "ADJ-1-37-8::FIBERTYPE=UNKNOWN,TARGSPANLOSS=0.00,MINSPANLOSS=0.00,SPANLOSSMARGIN=3.00,SPANLOSSSOURCE=UNKNOWN,BUNDLEID=\"\",LINEIN=\"\",LINEOUT=\"\",CRSIN=\"\",CRSOUT=\"\""
   "ADJ-1-37-10::FIBERTYPE=UNKNOWN,TARGSPANLOSS=0.00,MINSPANLOSS=0.00,SPANLOSSMARGIN=3.00,SPANLOSSSOURCE=UNKNOWN,BUNDLEID=\"\",LINEIN=\"\",LINEOUT=\"\",CRSIN=\"\",CRSOUT=\"\""
   "ADJ-1-37-14::FIBERTYPE=UNKNOWN,TARGSPANLOSS=0.00,MINSPANLOSS=0.00,SPANLOSSMARGIN=3.00,SPANLOSSSOURCE=UNKNOWN,BUNDLEID=\"\",LINEIN=\"\",LINEOUT=\"\",CRSIN=\"\",CRSOUT=\"\""
   "ADJ-1-37-16::FIBERTYPE=UNKNOWN,TARGSPANLOSS=0.00,MINSPANLOSS=0.00,SPANLOSSSOURCE=UNKNOWN,BUNDLEID=\"\",LINEIN=\"\",LINEOUT=\"\",CRSIN=\"\",CRSOUT=\"\""
   "ADJ-1-37-20::FIBERTYPE=UNKNOWN,TARGSPANLOSS=0.00,MINSPANLOSS=0.00,SPANLOSSMARGIN=3.00,SPANLOSSSOURCE=UNKNOWN,BUNDLEID=\"\",LINEIN=\"\",LINEOUT=\"\",CRSIN=\"\",CRSOUT=\"\""
   "ADJ-1-37-22::FIBERTYPE=UNKNOWN,TARGSPANLOSS=0.00,MINSPANLOSS=0.00,SPANLOSSMARGIN=3.00,SPANLOSSSOURCE=UNKNOWN,BUNDLEID=\"\",LINEIN=\"\",LINEOUT=\"\",CRSIN=\"\",CRSOUT=\"\""
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

`(ADJ-\d{1,3}-\d{1,3}-\d{1,3})::(.(SPANLOSSMARGIN=)?(\d{1,2}.\d{1,2})?)*`

You can try it here:

http://fiddle.re/qm6j86

Group 4 is the match for `SPANLOSSMARGIN=` , if `SPANLOSSMARGIN=` doesn't exists than group 3 will be `null`

Comment: I had to modify this to `(ADJ-\d{1,3}-\d{1,3}-\d{1,3})::(.(SPANLOSSMARGIN=(\d{1,2}.\d{1,2}))?)*` as Group 4 was returning 0.00 even if there's no `SPANLOSSMARGIN` tag. Is it OK?

Comment: @surz i said in my answer you need to check group 3 to see if a match was made

Comment: you are right, I'm directly using Group 4, so had to tweak a little bit, do you see any issue in this regex?

Comment: the one that you modified seems fine to me